# Por que o Box Alignment não está funcionando?

Tags: css, tailwind

Eu gostaria de criar um espaço entre `Register` e `Remember`, mas não está funcionando.

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div classs="container ">
    <div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen  space-y-4 border-2 items-center justify-center py-12 px-4">  
    <h2 class="text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">Todo Authentication</h2>
        <input type="text" class="border w-2/5 py-2 px-2 focus:placeholder-black " placeholder="Username" />
        <input type="password" class="border  w-2/5 py-2 px-2 focus:placeholder-black " placeholder="Password" />
        <div class="flex w-2/5 justify-between">
          <a href="">Register</a>
          <span class="space-x-2">
         <input type="checkbox">
Remember

</span>
         </div>
        <button class="border w-2/5 p-4 text-lg font-bold bg-blue-200 border-black rounded">Log in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

### Atualização

Resolvi o problema colocando uma width entre esses elementos.

Comment: Como assim espaço, que tipo de espaço, só uma pequena margem? Ou um de um lado e o outro do outro? Não ficou muito claro o que  vc realmente pretendo como resultado final

Comment: Eu atualizei o resultado com o FIX que eu queria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu lhe sugiro criar um novo arquivo para colocar estilos que você precisar e colocar de acordo com um nome/classe/id

Sem o arquivo você pode usar o `style="propriedade:valor`, para o que você quer, que é criar um espaço ficaria `style="margin-right: 10px"` ao colocar na tag `<a>` ou então `style="margin-left: 10px"` para a tag `<input>`

Aqui está dois exemplos para cada tag, (supondo que você irá estilizar a partir do html mesmo)

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div classs="container ">
    <div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen  space-y-4 border-2 items-center justify-center py-12 px-4">  
    <h2 class="text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">Todo Authentication</h2>
        <input type="text" class="border w-2/5 py-2 px-2 focus:placeholder-black " placeholder="Username" />
        <input type="password" class="border  w-2/5 py-2 px-2 focus:placeholder-black " placeholder="Password" />
        <div class="flex justify-between">
          <a href="" style="margin-right: 10px">Register</a>
          <input type="checkbox">Remember
        </div>
        <button class="border w-2/5 p-4 text-lg font-bold bg-blue-200 border-black rounded">Log in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div classs="container ">
    <div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen  space-y-4 border-2 items-center justify-center py-12 px-4">  
    <h2 class="text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">Todo Authentication</h2>
        <input type="text" class="border w-2/5 py-2 px-2 focus:placeholder-black " placeholder="Username" />
        <input type="password" class="border  w-2/5 py-2 px-2 focus:placeholder-black " placeholder="Password" />
        <div class="flex justify-between">
          <a href="">Register</a>
          <input type="checkbox" style="margin-left: 10px">Remember
        </div>
        <button class="border w-2/5 p-4 text-lg font-bold bg-blue-200 border-black rounded">Log in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```